# Its Possible Translate Java Encrpytion to PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

hello I'm trying to translate encrpytion from java to javascrip but still not same, is it possible to translate it from java ?

thanks

```
    public CryptoUtilities(@Value("${crypto.secret-key:zxcxczcxzczcxzcxz]}") String secretKey,
          @Value("${crypto.salt:cxzczxczxzcxcxz}") String salt)
          throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(UTF8), ITERATION_COUNT,
            KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
      }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) {
        try {
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
          byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(UTF8));
          return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
          throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
        }
      }


 var salt = 'cxzczxczxzcxcxz';
    var iv = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}';
    iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv);;
    var key = 'zxcxczcxzczcxzcxz';
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
    console.log('salt  '+ salt );
    console.log('iv  '+ iv );
    var key128Bits100Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(key, salt, { keySize: 256, iterations: 100 });
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("FullName#email@domain.com#08123123123", key128Bits100Iterations, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  });
    console.log(btoa(encrypted.toString()));
    console.log('bCFy3m3IFihX22FrcPSqAPf2kCMiyrjYTcSfT4Vhr9Y=');
```

is it possible to translate from java ? thanks

Comment: Your key on Java-side is "just" a string, so you can leave out the Base64-decoding on Javascript-side - just use the string as input for your PBKDF2-function.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the encoding of the key, there are the following issues:

- The Java code uses a zero IV, which must be passed in the JavaScript code as a `WordArray`, e.g. with

  ```
  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([], 16);
  ```
- The key size in the PBKDF2 call of the JavaScript code is to be specified in multiples of `word`s (4 bytes):

  ```
  keySize: 256 / 32
  ```

  This generates a 256 bits or 32 bytes AES key, i.e. AES-256.
  The naming `key128Bits100Iterations` used in the posted code implies that possibly a 16 bytes key should be applied. In this case `keySize: 128 / 32` would have to be used.
- `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` returns a [`CipherParams`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output) object. `toString()` returns the Base64 encoded ciphertext, i.e. `btoa()` is not needed.
- The key, or more precisely the passphrase for the PBKDF2 call must not be Base64 decoded, instead it can be passed as a string (s. comment) or alternatively as a `WordArray` created by parsing the string with the [`CryptoJS.enc.Utf8`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) encoder.
- CBC and PKCS7 are the default and do not need necessarily to be specified.

Overall:

```js
var passphrase = 'zxcxczcxzczcxzcxz'; 
var salt = 'cxzczxczxzcxcxz';
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([], 16); 

var key256Bits100Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, { keySize: 256 / 32, iterations: 100 }); 
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("FullName#email@domain.com#08123123123", key256Bits100Iterations, {iv: iv});

var encryptedB64 = encrypted.toString();
console.log(encryptedB64.replace(/(.{48})/g,'$1\n')); // yIJbXhsnlSTCS9olGhWQ8fRzS6gPUC35JIEGU0vYs+5cMHVIBrM48Nv8+e+1UmZa
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

which produces a ciphertext identical to the ciphertext of the Java code.

Note that a static IV (like a zero IV) is insecure. Usually a random IV is generated for each encryption. Likewise, a random salt is generated for each key derivation. Both are not secret and are passed along with the ciphertext, usually concatenated, e.g. `salt|iv|ciphertext`.
`iterations` is to be set as high as possible under the constraint of acceptable performance (`100` is usually too low).